# Visual Basic 2010 - Invalid CastException was unhandled

Tags: vb.net

I'm fairly new to visual basic. I was trying to make a program that generates code for you, based on whatever the user inputs. But whenever I click generate, I get this error

```
Invalid CastException was unhandled.
Conversion from string "//Generated using MAYAN.  Minecr" to type 'Double' is not valid."
```

It says it is affected by the line:

```
Code_Viewer.TextCodeViewer.Text = "//Generated using EASYMC.  EasyModCreator.tk" + vbNewLine
```

Here is my source code..

Thanks to anybody who helps! :)

http://pastebin.com/wHBbqK5K

I decided to post it on pastebin, it's easier to read.

Comment: It is an accurate exception, that string can't be converted to a Double.  Exactly what code does this and why it expects a number instead of a string is entirely unclear, you'll need to find it.  Look at the stack trace of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [& operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfx50zyk%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) instead of the [+ operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9c5t70w2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), e.g.:

```
Code_Viewer.TextCodeViewer.Text = "//Generated using EASYMC.  EasyModCreator.tk" & vbNewLine
```